# How can I find my test transaction from Get Started Guide code on the Stellar TestNetwork?

Tags: transactions, beginners, developersguide, testnet

I've been following along the ['Get Started'](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/transactions.html) guide on the Stellar Developer's site and practicing with the Java code that is provided in the 'Transactions' chapter.

When executing the sample code to send a payment over the Test Network, I get,  after about a minute, a response in the console back that the transaction of the PaymentOperation was a success. However, when checking the destination account that has received the payment (using a tool like stellarchain.io (switching to TestNet)), I am able to find the account itself, but I don't see the payment transaction that I executed. In my view, it should have been visible there. I guess I must be missing or misunderstand something, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transactions can contain one or many operations being payments one of them, so your payment should be in the transaction history but you have to look for it whether in code following the links provided, with an explorer, or fetching the operation directly by its Id using the Stellar RPC url.

http://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/operations/your-op-id

You could also get the latest operations using this RPC url:

GET /transactions/{hash}/operations{?cursor,limit,order}

Set the cursor=now, limit=10 and order=desc to get the latest operations (payments included) where surely you'll find your payment.

The Java SDK has wrapper methods around the RPC calls so you could use them once you get to that chapter.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to find them. Also noticed that it's better not to use 
the hard-coded accounts in the Get Started example code, but use your own ones instead.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell what went wrong:

- You could check your account on [Horizon](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/index.html#api-horizon) directly: `https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/<your-address>`
- or use a different explorer `https://testnet.steexp.com`

In case you don't see a XLM balance on `http://testnet.stellarchain.io/address/<your-address>` your account does not exist (yet).

When you test, you may want to watch the testnet [dashboard](https://dashboard.stellar.org/) (on the bottom of that site) for your transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Every transaction should have an XDR blob associated with it.

In order to troubleshoot your test transactions, you can breakdown the transaction you sent using the [XDR Viewer on Stellar Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test)

There's a lot to digest there but start with checking to make sure that the destination is correct, as well as the operation you performed is correct.